# How to pass a array to a method?

Tags: java, arrays

I define a method that can swap two specific character in a array, but when i wanna see the outcome I do not know how to pass a array in to my method.

```
public static int[] swap(int[] array, int x, int y){

    for(int i=0; i<array.length;i++){
        if(array[i] == array[x]) {
            int temp = array[x];
            array[x] = array[y];
            temp = array[y];
        }
    }

    return array;


}


public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(swap(, 0, 1));
}
```

what should I do to pass a whatever array I want in to swap method?

Comment: `swap(, 0, 1)` .. hmm, what "array" is that supposed to pass? [One should probably have been created first, with some useful data, and probably assigned to a variable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) .. Then `swap(theArray, 0, 1)` could be used.

Comment: @user2864740 why your name is user28xxxxx?

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Makes it easy to see in comments - last 3 are 740!

Comment: @user2864740 yeah. i mean why you got that username? mine is Randyka Yudhistira same as my google username

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira Stack Overflow gave it to me, along with a cute avatar! I've just not seen a reason to change it. (It also keeps me from being "less attached" - I've deleted two other accounts previously and I sense it's about time this one is due.. *shrug*, it sure makes looking up things harder when I do.)

Answer (score 0):

If your array is `int[] nums = {0,1,2,3,4,5}`, then you would just pass the entire array like so:

```
swap(nums,2,4);
```

And that should return `{0,1,4,3,2,5}`. By the way, your swap method is somewhat inefficient. There is no need to loop through the entire array the way you are doing. Here would be a better way of doing it:

```
public static void swap(int[] array, int x, int y){
     int temp = array[x];
     array[x] = array[y];
     array[y] = temp;
}
```

There is no need to return the array because it is not immutable.